I'm making a function for my project (car rental program) and I have an issue with a cancel a reservation function
first of all lets say I have 2 rented cars already:
ID,PlateNumber,StartDate,EndDate,TotalPrice (this line doesn't show in the csv file its just for reference)
output:
,,,, (this line is always empty and idk why)
3,123456Z,Tue May 07 01:00:00 2024,Wed May 08 01:00:00 2024,200.00$
3,789123B,Tue May 07 01:00:00 2024,Wed May 08 01:00:00 2024,100.00$

(the ID is the user who rented the cars)
and now let's say user 3 doesn't want the car of plate 123456Z
when I go ahead and delete the car and open the csv file, it all of a sudden looks like this:
output:
,,,Thu Jan 01 02:00:07 1970,
3,789123B,Thu Jan 01 02:00:00 1970, Thu Jan 01 02:00:07 1970,

and this is all the code related to it:
struct UserInformation {
    string ID;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string password;
    string email;
    string phoneNumber;
    string authority;

    void printUserInformation() const {
        cout << "ID: " << ID << endl;
        cout << "First Name: " << firstName << endl;
        cout << "Last Name: " << lastName << endl;
        cout << "Password: " << password << endl;
        cout << "Email: " << email << endl;
        cout << "Phone Number: " << phoneNumber << endl;
        cout << "Authority: " << authority << endl;
    }
};

struct CarsInformation {
    string type;
    string brand;
    string model;
    string year;
    string subType;
    string color;
    string plateNumber;
    string price;
    string availability;

    void printCarsInformation() const {
        cout << "Type: " << type << endl;
        cout << "Brand: " << brand << endl;
        cout << "Model: " << model << endl;
        cout << "Year: " << year << endl;
        cout << "SubType: " << subType << endl;
        cout << "Color: " << color << endl;
        cout << "Plate Number: " << plateNumber << endl;
        cout << "Price per day: " << price << endl;
        cout << "Availability: " << availability << endl;
    }
};

struct RentInformation {
    string ClientID;
    string CarPlateNumber;
    time_t RentStartDate;
    time_t RentEndDate;
    string TotalPriceForTheRent;
};

this one might have something to do with the empty line:
void appendRentInfoToCSV(const RentInformation& rentInfo) {
    ofstream outputFile("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\rented_cars.csv",  ios::out | ios::app);
    if (outputFile.is_open()) {
        char startDateStr[50];
        char endDateStr[50];

        strftime(startDateStr, sizeof(startDateStr), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", localtime(&rentInfo.RentStartDate));
        strftime(endDateStr, sizeof(endDateStr), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", localtime(&rentInfo.RentEndDate));

        outputFile << rentInfo.ClientID << ',' << rentInfo.CarPlateNumber << ','
                   << startDateStr << ',' << endDateStr << ','
                   << fixed << setprecision(2) << rentInfo.TotalPriceForTheRent << endl;
        cout << "Reservation information added successfully." << endl;
        outputFile.close(); // Close the file inside the if block
    } else {
        cerr << "Failed to open file for writing." << endl;
    }
}

this is the function:
void cancelRESERVATION(CarsInformation cars[], int& numCars, RentInformation rents[], int& numRents, UserInformation users[], int& numUsers, string userID) {
    // Open the rented_cars.csv file to read the reservations
    ifstream inputFile("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\rented_cars.csv");
    if (!inputFile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Failed to open file for reading." << endl;
        return;
    }

    // Read and display all reservations of the user
    bool hasReservations = false;
    int j = 1;
    string line;
    while (getline(inputFile, line)) {
        // Split the CSV line into fields
        stringstream ss(line);
        string field;
        string fields[5]; // Assuming 5 fields per line
        int fieldIndex = 0;
        while (getline(ss, field, ',')) {
            fields[fieldIndex++] = field;
        }

        // Check if the line corresponds to the current user's reservation
        if (fieldIndex == 5 && fields[0] == userID) {
            // Print reservation information
            cout << "Car #" << j++ << endl;
            cout << "Plate Number: " << fields[1] << endl;
            cout << "Start Date: " << fields[2] << endl;
            cout << "End Date: " << fields[3] << endl;
            cout << "Total Price: " << fields[4] << endl;

            hasReservations = true;
        }
    }
    inputFile.close();

    // If the user has no reservations, inform them and return
    if (!hasReservations) {
        cout << "You have no reservations to cancel." << endl;
        return;
    }

    // Ask the user to enter the plate number of the car they want to cancel the reservation for
    string plateNumber;
    cout << "Enter the plate number of the car you want to cancel the reservation for: ";
    cin >> plateNumber;

    // Find the reservation with the given plate number and user ID
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < numRents; i++) {
        if (rents[i].CarPlateNumber == plateNumber && rents[i].ClientID == userID) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If the reservation is found, cancel it
    if (index != -1) {
        // Move all reservations after the canceled one one position to the left
        for (int i = index; i < numRents - 1; i++) {
            rents[i] = rents[i + 1];
        }
        numRents--;

        // Update the car's availability to "available" in the cars array
        for (int i = 0; i < numCars; i++) {
            if (cars[i].plateNumber == plateNumber) {
                cars[i].availability = "available";
                break;
            }
        }

        // Rewrite the updated list of cars to the CSV file
        ofstream outputFile("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\cars.csv");
        if (outputFile.is_open()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numCars; i++) {
                outputFile << cars[i].type << ',' << cars[i].brand << ',' << cars[i].model << ',' << cars[i].year << ',' << cars[i].subType << ',' << cars[i].color << ',' << cars[i].plateNumber << ',' << cars[i].price << ',' << cars[i].availability << endl;
            }
            outputFile.close();
            cout << "Car availability updated successfully." << endl;
        } else {
            cerr << "Failed to open file for writing." << endl;
        }

        // Rewrite the updated list of reservations to the CSV file
        ofstream outputFile2("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\rented_cars.csv");
        if (outputFile2.is_open()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numRents; i++) {
                char startDateStr[50];
                char endDateStr[50];

                strftime(startDateStr, sizeof(startDateStr), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", localtime(&rents[i].RentStartDate));
                strftime(endDateStr, sizeof(endDateStr), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", localtime(&rents[i].RentEndDate));

                outputFile2 << rents[i].ClientID << ',' << rents[i].CarPlateNumber << ','
                            << startDateStr << ',' << endDateStr << ','
                            << fixed << setprecision(2) << rents[i].TotalPriceForTheRent << endl;
            }
            outputFile2.close();
            cout << "Updated reservation information written to the CSV file." << endl;
        } else {
            cerr << "Failed to open file for writing." << endl;
        }

        cout << "Reservation canceled successfully." << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Reservation not found for the provided plate number." << endl;
    }
}

I do not have anything in mind, I just want it to work

Try using a debugger to step through the code line by line, while monitoring variables and their values, to see what's going on.

I also recommend you try to make your code simpler. A function should do only one thing, not three or four like your cancelRESERVATION function. Split it up into smaller and simpler functions. That way it's easier to debug and (more importantly) to test the functions one by one. It also make the code easier to read, understand and maintain.

And as a tip for future programs: Don't write large pieces of code without any kind of testing. Basically, start with an empty main function. Build the code with lots of extra warnings enabled and treated as errors. Once it builds cleanly, test the code you have in all possible ways. And when it passes all tests, add a very small bit of code, perhaps only one or two lines. Build and test as before. That makes it much easier to isolate and debug problems when they occur. And with my previous tip, tend to make the code much better.

@Someprogrammerdude okay thanks ill try to make the funtion into pieces and see if it works

Why read the file first? You have the information you need in rents. You seem very keen on reading and writing the file when you don't need to. (And you don't need users and numUsers.)

@molbdnilo yes you are right, sorry im a beginner and this project is way above what we learned but I have to get a good grade lol.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Start with figuring out why there is always an empty line. (I suspect that there's a bug when you first write it that makes you write an empty entry.)
